# RPD Rowcount > 0 but no data is shown

Tags: oracle, obiee

Edit: Talking about the Repository(RPD) file from the BI Server(obiee)

I'm running into an odd behavior where i can update the row count in the physical layer but when I click on show data it can't find any. It says empty ResultSet.

I logged into SQL Developer with the same user as in the connection pool and there i can see the actual data. What could possibly be the cause of this difference?

Comment: What kind of source?

Comment: Read this...   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: edited original post

Comment: Hi, please include detailed repro steps. Are you sure the Connection Pool being used points to the exact same database that you added the record to in SQL Developer? Are you using replication?